# jQuery onclick not getting triggered

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a list on my webpage. When someone clicks on a list item, some javascript should be executed. For example a alert. I get this working on a almost empty page, for example see this code:

```
 <ul class="uniquelist">
        <li id="1">clickable 1</li>
        <li id="2">clickable 2</li>
        <li id="3">clickable 3</li>
        <li id="4">clickable 4</li>
        <li id="5">clickable 5</li>
    </ul>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.uniquelist li').click(function(){ 
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      alert(id);
    });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Wafk/1/

If I put this code in my "complete" webpage with a lot more code, it doesn't work anymore. It's a little bit to much to post all the code here so I hope someone has some clues of where i need to look at.

The class of the list is off course unique, there are no other elements with the same class.

**Edit:**
This list is loaded after the page is loaded. This is the output of my autocomplete!

Comment: Perhaps you are adding the list after the page is already loaded?

Comment: Do you get some error message? Having other elements with the same class should not break this code.

Comment: You said, `If I put this code in my "complete" webpage with a lot more code, it doesn't work anymore`. So, essentially you're showing us the part that **works** instead of the actual part that doesn't? i.e. the **clues**? And please note how you should be naming your IDs: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

Comment: @MMeersseman The list is indeed loaded after the page is loaded. The list is populated on a autocomplete!

Comment: @TerryYoung True, I know, I can't start with a digit. The idea was to put a product ID in the attribute "ID" so I can get the product ID by the attribute ID. I thought this was a nice idea! There is no other need for using the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're adding the list after page load, you need to use `on()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.uniquelist li', function(){ 
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
  });
});
```

`body` maybe exchanged for any ascendant selector present on the page when it loads - the closer the selector you chose, the less DOM traversal jQuery will have to do.

Comment: I found my answer and was just writing it while your answer appeard! So I will mark your answer as a answer! Tnx!